# Android Bluetooth Broadcast Receiver not receiving

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

We have a hardware that will try to connect to the android phone, so opening a server socket on the android phone and listening will work.

The problem I'm having now is we have a broadcast receiver listening for ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED.

The broadcast receiver is not receiving those event, neither is the server socket accepting connection from the hardware it just stay at the `accept()` method.

**To make it work I had to make a connection from the Android Phone to the hardware first** then from that point I'm getting all the ACL_CONNECTED/ACL_DISCONNECTED events and my server socket is accepting connection from the hardware.

Is this a normal behavior? That the Android has to first make a connection once to the hardware before it can receive the ACL_CONNECTED/ACL_DISCONNECTED events? Once I did that, I will always receive the events, until I do like a factory reset on the device then it's the same issue again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to figure out what exactly is wrong without any code provided. However I am going to fathom a guess. The most common reason for connections to fail is because the appropriate [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is not provided.

In most cases the most generic UUID for common devices such as printers,keyboards, headsets etc is 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. When you ask your phone to connect to such a device and you have used this UUID most of the time it will connect. However when you tell your hardware device to connect to your phone(initialize connection), if it does not have the appropriate UUID for your phone the connection cannot be established.

So in summary:
Check your UUID definitions.

### UPDATE

Does your android side code look this?

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
 
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
 
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
 
    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
 
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
 
        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }
 
    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

If this is the case then it is a client not a server. And your hardware is listening for a client to connect to it rather then the other way around.

Comment: Is there a way to know which UUID the hardware is using when his making a client connection to the Android Phone?

Comment: The UUID can be thought of as a unique ID so both your Android phone and your hardware device need to use the same ID in order to connect. However when programming your code you need to know which one (hardware or device) is going to be the sever and which one is going to be the client. I would read the android bluetooth documentation again to understand this concept. Usually the hardware is the server because it provides the data while the android just wants to use it (so its the client).

Comment: The problem I believe is that when you are trying to connect with your hardware the android is not set up as a server so it is not actively looking for a connection. Therefore the hardware will never be able to connect to it unless the phone initiates the connection. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: My android app is the server because I'm opening a server socket and listening on it. And the hardware is configure to be client, because it is a kind of medical device where it will send heart rate data. Like I said, all works fine if I first initiate a connection from the Android as a client to the hardware. And the Android will start accepting connection from the hardware (the client). So it does work, but only if I initiated a connection to the hardware from the android app. So I was wondering if this normal? But I think you are on to something with the UUID...

Comment: The server device and the client device each obtain the required BluetoothSocket in different ways.The server will receive it when an incoming connection is accepted. The client will receive it when it opens an RFCOMM channel to the server.

Comment: I need to see the embedded code for your hardware. Did you write that?

Comment: No I didn't, but I know the hardware is using the connectblue obs411 chip, if that can help.

Comment: Also if your hardware is set up to be a particular way(server) then it cannot create a connection,  but only respond to a initiation request. This is the case with most off shelf devices.

Comment: The code you posted is a client code. In my Android app, it is opening a server socket. Like this BluetoothServerSocket  serverSocket = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("test", MY_UUID); serverSocket.accept();

Comment: But that doesn't work until my app first make a client connection to the hardware then serversocket accepts connections. But once I do this. I can skip the client connection (Android to hardware) and my server will always accept the connection from the hardware. As if Android registers somewhere it already once talk to this hardware and I can accept connection from it ...

Comment: Maybe your hardware only looks for paired devices and not all discoverable devices?

Comment: try getUuids(), it may return the UUID of the hardware.